# (AS3) add active state button code to the following code

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button

I am struggling to figure out how to code an active state for the button/s (show current page) Here is what I have so far:

```
stop();

  function handleClick (p_event:MouseEvent) :void
  {
    if(p_event.target == logo_btn)
    {
        gotoAndStop(1, "Home");
    }
    if(p_event.target == home_btn)
    {
        gotoAndStop(1, "Home");
    }
    if(p_event.target == portfolio_btn)
    {
        gotoAndStop(1, "Portfolio");
    }
    if(p_event.target == press_btn)
    {
        gotoAndStop(1, "Press");
    }
    if(p_event.target == links_btn)
    {
        gotoAndStop(1, "Links");
    }
    if(p_event.target == contact_btn)
    {
        gotoAndStop(1, "Contact");
    }
  }

  stop();

  home_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleClick);
  portfolio_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleClick);
  press_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleClick);
  links_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleClick);
  contact_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleClick);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First must recreate a Button that have a 2 frames, 1 frame is inactive ui 2 frame is active ui . they also 1 frame `stop();` script. In Main timeline declare temporary variable, and stored current selected Button at MouseClick Handler. next Active / InActive task execution.

```
var selectedButton:MovieClip;
function handleClick(p_event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var clickedClip:MovieClip = p_event.target as MovieClip;

    if (clickedClip == logo_btn)
    {
        if (selectedButton)
            selectedButton.gotoAndStop(1);
        selectedButton = logo_btn;
        selectedButton.gotoAndStop(2);
        gotoAndStop(1, "Home");
    }
    else if (clickedClip == home_btn)
    {
        if (selectedButton)
            selectedButton.gotoAndStop(1);
        selectedButton = home_btn;
        selectedButton.gotoAndStop(2);
        gotoAndStop(1, "Home");
    }
    else if (clickedClip == portfolio_btn)
    {
        if (selectedButton)
            selectedButton.gotoAndStop(1);
        selectedButton = portfolio_btn;
        selectedButton.gotoAndStop(2);
        gotoAndStop(1, "Portfolio");
    }
    else if (clickedClip == press_btn)
    {
        if (selectedButton)
            selectedButton.gotoAndStop(1);
        selectedButton = press_btn;
        selectedButton.gotoAndStop(2);
        gotoAndStop(1, "Press");
    }
    else if (clickedClip == links_btn)
    {
        if (selectedButton)
            selectedButton.gotoAndStop(1);
        selectedButton = links_btn;
        selectedButton.gotoAndStop(2);
        gotoAndStop(1, "Links");
    }
    else if (clickedClip == contact_btn)
    {
        if (selectedButton)
            selectedButton.gotoAndStop(1);
        selectedButton = contact_btn;
        selectedButton.gotoAndStop(2);
        gotoAndStop(1, "Contact");
    }
}
```

Here is my sample code: [ActiveButtonTest](http://www.fileswap.com/dl/y3NecuSsUA/)

Comment: I understand what you're saying and it would work if I created an mc from the get go but I have to create a button first and then convert button on down state to movie clip. Will it work that way? (also my over state is an mc since I am applying filters to it.

Comment: Do you think the same way as the above process. no difficult. `gotoAndStop()` replace to your code. think about the following. `gotoAndStop(1)`=> remove filiters, `gotoAndStop(2)` => set filters